# How to check if a php session changes value

Tags: php, session

I got three websites on one domain, the website changes depending on what session is active and has some features like seeing a list of your last visited products.

The problem is those products are stored in a session, and when you change website the products from the other site are still loaded.

How can I check if for example `$_SESSION['site']` changes its value?

`$_SESSION['laatstbekeken']` is my session with stored products, so I want something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['site'] changes){
    unset($_SESSION["laatstbekeken"]);
}
```

Comment: Differentiate the each session like this `$_SESSION['site_1']`,`$_SESSION['site_2']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the 'site' in a variable in the session to compare it to the current 'sessions site' every time, like this:

```
if($_SESSION['site'] != $_SESSION['last_site']) {
    unset($_SESSION["laatstbekeken"]);
    $_SESSION['last_site'] = $_SESSION['site']; // Store the new 'site'
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks that works, i'll accept in 2 minutes.